# network "fabric" is declared as external, but could not be found. You need to create a swarm-scoped network before the stack is deployed

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm

Did anyone know what is the solution for below error? Thank you.

```
> Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and
> CLI delay of '3' seconds Continue? [Y/n] Y proceeding ... 2018-09-12
> 06:37:03.473 UTC [main] main -> INFO 001 Exiting.....
> LOCAL_VERSION=1.1.0 DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.1.0 Ignoring deprecated
> options:
> 
> container_name: Setting the container name is not supported.
> 
> network "fabric" is declared as external, but could not be found. You
> need to create a swarm-scoped network before the stack is deployed
> ERROR !!!! Unable to start network
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you share additional details like docker compose files that you've created and your network setup.

Comment: Hi, I already solved this problem. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: how did you solved it?